# PHP reference - The confusions

Tags: php, pass-by-reference, php-5.6

I find that the reference in the code below is confusing,

```
$a = 4;
$b = &$a;
var_dump($b);

$a = 10;
var_dump($b); // 10

$b = 100;
var_dump($a); // 100 but shouldn't it be 10?
```

Value of `$b` is a reference to `$a` and `$a` is **never** a reference to `$b`.

But why when I change the value of `$b`. The value of `$a` changes as well?

Comment: I'm also confused but I think it's because of "C programming". In C, it would work as you expect, but in PHP, it may be different... In C, "$b" would just contain the address of "$a", so if you change "$b", it won't contain anymore the address of "$a"...

Comment: that's what I thought it should be in PHP! It is not obviously!

Comment: It must be because there are no types in PHP... In C, you add "*" to the type, to say it will be a pointer. here, when you declare "$b", it will be a variable with the same address of "$a", not a variable containing the address of "$a"...

Answer (score 4):

In the line: `$b = &$a;` The variable `$b` is being set up as a reference to `$a` (as in it will point to the same memory location as `$b`). In this respect `$b` essentially becomes an alias or another way of accessing and modifying `$a`.

This [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) explains pointers in C++ (it's important to stress that this is not C++ but the link explains pointers / references well).

I hope this helps.

Comment: so they are pointing to each other actually in another words - in PHP?

Comment: They're not pointing to each other, `$b` is pointing to `$a`. In memory `$a` would hold the value of 100 and `$b` would hold the value of `$a`'s memory address. It literally "points" to `$a`.

Comment: why would $100 holds the value of 100? it is not pointing to anything, isn't?

Comment: @EM-Creations Are you sure it works as in C++ ? I think in fact the confusion comes from C/C++, since it doesn't work the same way...

Comment: I'm referencing the last assignment. At the end of the program's execution, `$a` would hold the value of 100. This is because `$b` is essentially an alias (another name) for `$a` programmatically after you set it up as a reference / pointer to `$a`.

Comment: @Random I didn't say it works the same as in C++, I just added the link as it explains what pointers are.

Comment: But I point that the OP seems to know exactly how pointers work in C/C++, and this is why he is confused...

Comment: Upvoted for the use of `alias`. It is a really good way to define references in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`$b = &$a;` represents their values are equal if you define `$b` then `$a` value becomes equal to that of `$b` respectively.

[Check out this link for more information](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)